# Mixing Monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to work with Ubigraph in haskell, but I believe my problem is more generic. I'm trying to compile:

```
import Graphics.Ubigraph
import Control.Monad
import System.Posix.Unistd

main = do
    h <- initHubigraph "http://127.0.0.1:20738/RPC2"
    runHubigraph op h

op = do
  clear
  vs <- mapM (const newVertex) [0..200]
  mapM_ (setVAttr (VShape Sphere)) vs
  putStrLn "something"
  let bind i = zipWithM (\a b -> newEdge (a,b)) vs (drop i vs ++ take i vs)
  mapM_ bind [1..15]
  mapM_ (removeVertex) vs
  return ()
```

and I am getting

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader.ReaderT
>                                 Ubigraph IO a0'
>             with actual type `IO ()'
> In the return type of a call of `putStrLn'
> In a stmt of a 'do' expression: putStrLn "something"
> In the expression:
>   do { clear;
>        vs <- mapM (const newVertex) [0 .. 200];
>        mapM_ (setVAttr (VShape Sphere)) vs;
>        putStrLn "something";
>        .... }
> ```

I can see how the type of op is being implied as something different from the return type of putStrLn, but I am not sure how I would reengineer this code to compile properly. Can I simply change the return type of the op function?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your call to `putStrLn` buried down in `op` is in the `IO` monad. You will need to lift it into the `Ubigraph` monad, using

```
 liftIO $ putStrLn "foo"
```

Such lifting functions help you access monadic functions lower in the stack. In this case, `Ubigraph` is a Reader monad composed with the IO monad, and the IO monad is at the bottom. So things in IO must be lifted.

`liftIO` is from the `MonadIO` class, [in the transformers package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html).